# Detecting white text on a bright background with tesseract

Tags: java, opencv, tesseract, tess4j, pokemon-go

I'm having issues reading white text on a bright background, it finds the text itself but it cannot really translate it correctly.

The image:
[image]

The result I keep getting is `LanEerus` which is not that far off, to be honest.

What I'm wondering is what image pre-processing could fix this? I'm using photoshop to manually pre-process it before I try to do it with code, to find what should work first.

I've tried making it a bitmap, but that makes the *borders* of the text pretty bad, resulting in tesseract just translating it to random characters.

Inverting colors and/or grayscaling doesn't seem to do the trick, either.

Anyone have any ideas? I know it's a pretty bad background for the text for this case. Trust me, I wish that the background was different!

My code for the tests:

```java
File file = new File("C:\\tess\\lando.png");
ITesseract tess = new Tesseract();
tess.setDatapath("tessdata");

System.out.println(tess.doOCR(file));
```

**EDIT**
I have read through [Improving the quality](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html) but couldn't get those tips to work.

**EDIT 2**
After using OpenCV to preprocess the image with grayscale, inverting colors, gaussian blur and adaptive threshold. I get this result of the image but no better reading. If anything, worse..
[image]

Comment: Try canny edge detection -> then ocr

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one possible solution. This is in Python, but it should be clear enough for a Java port. We will apply a method called *gained division*. The idea is that you try to build a model of the background and then weight each input pixel by that model. The output gain should be relatively constant during most of the image. This will get rid of most of the background color variation. We can use a `morphological` chain to clean the result a little bit, let's see the code:

```
# imports:
import cv2
import numpy as np
# OCR imports:
from PIL import Image
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders

# image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "c552h.png"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)

# Get local maximum:
kernelSize = 5
maxKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernelSize, kernelSize))
localMax = cv2.morphologyEx(inputImage, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, maxKernel, None, None, 1, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)

# Perform gain division
gainDivision = np.where(localMax == 0, 0, (inputImage/localMax))

# Clip the values to [0,255]
gainDivision = np.clip((255 * gainDivision), 0, 255)

# Convert the mat type from float to uint8:
gainDivision = gainDivision.astype("uint8")
```

The first step is to apply gain division, the operations you need are straightforward: a morphological `closing` with a big rectangular `structuring element` and some data type conversions, be careful with the latter ones. This is the image you should see after the method is applied:

[image]

Very cool, the background is almost gone. Let's get a binary image using Otsu's Thresholding:

```
# Convert RGB to grayscale:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(gainDivision, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Get binary image via Otsu:
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

This is the binary image:

[image]

We have a nice image of the edges of the text. We can get a black-background and white-text if we `Flood-Fill` the background with white. However, we should be careful of the characters, because if a character is broken, the `Flood-Fill` operation will erase it. Let's first assure our characters are closed by applying a morphological `closing`:

```
# Set kernel (structuring element) size:
kernelSize = 3
# Set morph operation iterations:
opIterations = 1

# Get the structuring element:
morphKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernelSize, kernelSize))

# Perform closing:
binaryImage = cv2.morphologyEx( binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, morphKernel, None, None, opIterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101 )
```

This is the resulting image:

[image]

As you see, the edges are a lot stronger and, most importantly, are closed. Now, we can `Flood-Fill` the background with white color. Here, the `Flood-Fill` seed point is located at the image origin (`x = 0`, `y = 0`):

```
# Flood fill (white + black):
cv2.floodFill(binaryImage, mask=None, seedPoint=(int(0), int(0)), newVal=(255))
```

We get this image:

[image]

We are almost there. As you can see, the holes inside of some characters (e.g., the "a", "d" and "o") are not filled - this can produce noise to the `OCR`. Let's try to fill them. We can exploit the fact that these holes are all *children* of a parent contour. We can isolate the children contour and, again, apply a `Flood-Fill` to fill them. But first, do not forget to invert the image:

```
# Invert image so target blobs are colored in white:
binaryImage = 255 - binaryImage

# Find the blobs on the binary image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binaryImage, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Process the contours:
for i, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Get contour hierarchy:
    currentHierarchy = hierarchy[0][i][3]

    # Look only for children contours (the holes):
    if currentHierarchy != -1:

        # Get the contour bounding rectangle:
        boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        # Get the dimensions of the bounding rect:
        rectX = boundRect[0]
        rectY = boundRect[1]
        rectWidth = boundRect[2]
        rectHeight = boundRect[3]

        # Get the center of the contour the will act as
        # seed point to the Flood-Filling:
        fx = rectX + 0.5 * rectWidth
        fy = rectY + 0.5 * rectHeight

        # Fill the hole:
        cv2.floodFill(binaryImage, mask=None, seedPoint=(int(fx), int(fy)), newVal=(0))

# Write result to disk:
cv2.imwrite("text.png", binaryImage, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0])
```

This is the resulting mask:

[image]

Cool, let's apply the `OCR`. I'm using `pyocr`:

```
txt = tool.image_to_string(
    Image.open("text.png"),
    lang=lang,
    builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
)

print(txt)
```

The output:

```
Landorus
```

Comment: Looks very cool! Going to give it a go during the week.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to perform the gain division since NumPy is not available for java. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried making a python script to call from java, when I copy your code it creates the images perfectly. However when I try to read it, it translates to: `Beyaleleyaels`

Comment: @JonathanÖhrström I’m sorry, I can’t help you configuring your OCR engine. I used pyocr. I checked again with an [online demo](http://195.148.30.97/cgi-bin/ocr.py) of Tesseract and the text gets properly recognized. 
[Here’s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65473330/opencv-python-how-to-remove-the-gray-pixels-around-the-date-text/65487302#65487302) a non-vectorized implementation of gain division in Python, in case you still need it.

Comment: No worries, I used java to read the preprocessed image and that worked splendid. Sadly it only worked for that specific image. When it had another text it removed some of the characters. I think I'm going to have to re-evaluate this feature for the bot!

Comment: This works great for one of my projects. However when trying it from a picture capturing a blue LCD screen in my car the contours found are around 240k which takes forever, so I tried changing it to RETR_TREE instead of RETR_EXTERNAL which just results in the image becoming completely black with some white noise dots. Any idea on how to fix this?